# VC++ directories acting strange

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker

Lately, I've gotten some weird linker errors.

I've been taught that there's two ways to work with libraries:

via

```
Project Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories
Project Properties > VC++ Directories > Library Directories
```

or via

```
Project Properties > C/C++  > General > Additional Include Directories
Project Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories
Project Properties > Linker > Input   > Additional Dependencies
```

Lately, sometimes when I use the VC++ Directories way, I get a linker error saying that there's no definition for some function. When I add the library file that the function definition is in to the Additional Dependencies, it suddenly finds it.
But if you use VC++ Directories, normally you're not supposed to use Additional Dependencies at all, right?

This has happened multiple times now and has left me more than confused. It worked fine on past projects, but not anymore. Sometimes the VC++ way even work on another PC, but not on mine.
I have always worked with VS2010, and am still working with VS2010.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on?

Comment: VS seems to exhibit very unusual behavior when working over SMB.
Is it possible that any of the directories in use are on a network share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you specified the additional include directories, Visual Studio does not automatically try to link all library files present when you build your project.  You must take the additional step of adding the library file name to your additional dependencies list.  The additional include directories only helps to avoid writing the whole file path in your additional dependencies list.

An alternative to modifying the additional dependencies list is to use the [#pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) directive.  Specifically, use

```
    #pragma comment("[lib file name]")
```

This will direct the linker to link that file in your build.

Comment: That clarifies it. Thanks!
However, I'm talking about VC++ directories here. Those are called "Include Directories" without "additional". Either you understood my question wrong, or you made a typo.